# Can't display chart.js after fadeOut the pageloader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chart.js, materialize

I use preloader screen of MaterializeCSS Framework when loading.
But when loaded. My chart that I create with Chart.js isn't display after fade the preloader out. Can someone look my code from [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phongphan117/d94c3wz6/) solve the problem?

```js
//Preloader
$(window).load(function() {
});
function show() {
 $('#preloader').fadeOut(500);
 $('#canvas').delay(500).fadeIn();
};

setTimeout(show, 3000);

//Chart.js
var radarChartData = {
    labels: ["Eating", "Drinking", "Sleeping", "Designing", "Coding", "Cycling", "Running"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
        }
    ]
};
window.onload = function(){
    window.myRadar = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Radar(radarChartData, {
        responsive: true
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="http://materializecss.com/js/init.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.96.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="valign-wrapper" id="preloader" style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="valign center-align" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="preloader-wrapper big active" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
            <div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue">
                <div class="circle-clipper left"><div class="circle"></div></div>
                <div class="gap-patch"><div class="circle"></div></div>
                <div class="circle-clipper right"><div class="circle"></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="spinner-layer spinner-red">
                <div class="circle-clipper left"><div class="circle"></div></div>
                <div class="gap-patch"><div class="circle"></div></div>
                <div class="circle-clipper right"><div class="circle"></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="spinner-layer spinner-yellow">
                <div class="circle-clipper left"><div class="circle"></div></div>
                <div class="gap-patch"><div class="circle"></div></div>
                <div class="circle-clipper right"><div class="circle"></div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="spinner-layer spinner-green">
                <div class="circle-clipper left"><div class="circle"></div></div>
                <div class="gap-patch"><div class="circle"></div></div>
                <div class="circle-clipper right"><div class="circle"></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>Wait a minute...</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="chartcanvas" style="width:30%;">
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="450" style="display: none"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the chart initialization into the fadeIn call back

```
$('#canvas').delay(500).fadeIn(function() {
    window.myRadar = ...
```

If you need to fadeIn the chart as well, first show the canvas element with opacity 0 (or visibility hidden), initialize the chart and then fade it in.

If the canvas element (or sometimes the parent, when `responsive` is set) has no size when `new Chart` is called the height and width is taken as 0 and the chart is not visibly drawn.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/1jd9bmgo/

Comment: Thank a lot. And sorry for my skill.

Comment: No worries! It's a problem everyone runs into when they do that bit. Cheers!